# No. of 4 digit numbers such that any two digits differ by more than 1.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

Let $\;a_1a_2a_3a_4\;$ be the decimal representation of a $4$-digit number. This number is said to be “non-
adjacent” if for any pair $(i, j)$, where $1 \leq i, j \leq 4$ and $i \neq j$, $|ai – aj| > 1$.

Let P be the probability that a $4$-digit number chosen randomly is “non-adjacent”, then P is equal to?

The sample space is obviously $9*10^3$, but I am almost clueless on how to approach the favorable cases. Suppose, that $0$ is not a part of our number. There are 9 ways to chose the first digit, and $7$ for the second, but after the second, the cases start branching out and there seems to be too many possibilities.

The "solution" to this problem, simply states (without explanation):

Non-adjacent numbers with $0$ = $\binom{6}{3}*3*3!$

Non-adjacent numbers without $0$ = $\binom{6}{4}*4!$.

I fail to see the significance of $6$ here.

Comment: Still stuck. What next, after chosing 2 digits from the 4 in total?

Comment: The use of the word "adjacent" is confusing me.  I presume that $1358$ is acceptable.  What about $1324$?

Comment: I believe 1324 isnt acceptable. There is no additional constraint on $i$ and $j$. ANY two digits must differ by more than , i.e, any two digits arent adjacent, is the way I see it.

Comment: So, imagine that the digits need to be ascending.  How many possibilities are there e.g. $1357$, $1358$, etc.  I guess that $0$ is not accepted as an initial digit so that it will need some extra handling,

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the significance of $6$ in given solution:

Without $0$, we first choose $4$ distinct numbers $y_0<y_1<y_2<y_3$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We have $\binom{6}{4}$ options. Then let $x_i=y_i+i$ be the four digits of our number. There are $4!$ permutations of these digits, for the total of $\binom{6}{4}\times 4!$ qualifying numbers in this case.

With $0$, the method is similar, with $x_0=y_0=0$, and not counting permutations that begin with $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the four digits be $a, b , c, d$ with $a< b< c< d$ and we know $d\ge c+2\ge b+4 \ge a+6$.  And $0\le a < a+6 \le d \le 9$ so  $0\le a \le 3$ and $6\le d\le 9$.

If we let $b' = b-2; c'=c-4; d'=d-6$ we have a case we $a\le b' \le c'\le d'$ and $0\le a,b',c',d' \le 3$ which should be a more familiar problem.

We can use stars and bars to solve this.  There are $4$ stars (the digits $a,b',c',d'$ aligned in a row) and there are $3$ bars (stakes to place between the variables to indicate when the values switch from one value of $0,1$ or $2$ to the next value $1,2$ or $3$)--- [so for instance the case where $a=0;b'=1;c'=2;d'=3$ would be represented as $[\text{start at }0]a[\text{switch to }1]b[\text{switch to }2]c[\text{switch to } 3]d]\approx a1b2c3d \approx *|*|*|*$ while, going the other way the pattern $|**||**$ would mean $1ab23cd\approx [\text{start at }0][\text{switch to }1]ab[\text{switch to } 2][\text{switch to }3]$ which means $a=b'=1; c'=d'=3$.]---

So there are ${7\choose 3} = \frac {7!}{3!4!} = 35$ ways of choosing the values of $a, b', c', d'$ and $35$ ways of choosing $a, b=b'+2, c=c'+4, d=d'+6$.

And once you have $a,b,c,d$ there and $4!$ ways to arrange them so that there are $35*4! = 840$ such numbers.... except none of them can start with the digit $0$ (else it'd be a $3$ digit number)

So must subtract the case $a=0$ and $a$ is placed in the front and .... oh, bugger....

Okay without $0$ then if we did all the above we would have $1\le a,b',c',d' \le 3$ and when we get to the stars and bars part with have essentially $2$ bars and $4$ stars as we must always start with a fixed bar (we must *immediately* switch from $0$ to $1$).

So there are ${6\choose 2} = {6\choose 4}$ ways to do that and ${6\choose 4}4!$ total ways with no $0$s.

....

Now lets consider with a $0$.  Well, that would be the same as finding a $3$ digit non-adjacent number with no $0$s and sticking $0$ zero in it somewhere.

For three digit number with no $0$ was have, like above $2$ bars, and $3$ stars and $3!$ ways of arranging that digits so ${5\choose 2}3!$.  and ther are $3$ places to put the zero into it.

So ${5\choose 2}3!*3$.

Answer (score 0):

A "non-adjacent" number will have four distinct digits. Here are the possibilities:

$$\begin{array}{c} \{0,2,4,6\} \\ \{0,2,4,7\} \\ \vdots \\ \{0,5,7,9\} \\ \{1,3,5,7\} \\ \vdots \\ \{3,5,7,9\}\end{array}$$

In each of these possibilities, we want to choose a system of finding "available" numbers. So, we say that when a digit is chosen, so too is the digit one less than it. So, choosing $9$ also chooses $8$. Choosing $8$ also chooses $7$. Etc. Down to choosing $0$, which does not choose any additional numbers as there are no digits smaller than zero. Thus, with any selection of digits that includes $0$, you wind up with $3$ digits that cannot be chosen. With any selection of digits that does not include zero, you have $4$ digits that cannot be selected.

Suppose we have a $0$ in the number. We know that we cannot start a number with zero, so it must be one of the three digits after the leading digit. There are still three more numbers to choose. There are also three "forbidden" numbers. So, of the $9$ remaining digits, we cannot choose $3$, and there are $6$ remaining. Of those six, choose $3$. Then choose a position for the $0$ (there are three possibilities). Then permute the other three digits.

Suppose we do not have a $0$ in the number. Now, there are four forbidden numbers. Of the ten digits, four cannot be used, so there are six possibilities. We must choose four of them. Then, we permute them.